# DOM with multiple namespaces

Tags: java, dom, xml-namespaces

How do I go about to create an XML in Java with DOM that looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <ns2:AuditHeader xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.rnab.nl/giraal/AuditHeader/1.0">
      <MessageID>2014101314101012294900000</MessageID>
      <RelatesTo>pway://rnab/distributie/CreateCreditTransferReply/01</RelatesTo>
      <To>mq://rnab/giraal/OM</To>
      <Action>mq://rnab/giraal/OM/CreateCreditTransfer/01</Action>
      <From>pway://rnab/distributie</From>
    </ns2:AuditHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: which library are you using to generate XMLs

Comment: I am using org.w3c.dom.Attr;
org.w3c.dom.DOMException;
org.w3c.dom.DOMImplementation;
org.w3c.dom.Document;
org.w3c.dom.Element;
org.w3c.dom.Text;

Comment: This looks like SOAP, I suggest using a SOAP library. For DOM look at `Document.createElementNS()`.